# Alter Nginx reverse proxy cache header from Public to Private

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache, http-headers, headers

I have an Nginx cache server getting content from an origin server, the origin server sets `Cache-Control` to `Public` so my Nginx cache server can cache the content and make less requests to origin. But when serving to users, I don't want it to send the cache as `Public` anymore, but set it to `Private` so others (outside of this network) cannot cache it or modify it.

I still need it to pass a max-age and tried to do it by a custom header sent, but the `if` condition fails.

**this alone works OK:**

```
add_header Cache-Control "private, max-age=$upstream_http_adr_private_cache_seconds";
```

**this condition fails**

```
if ($upstream_http_adr_private_cache_seconds) {

    add_header Cache-Control "private, max-age=$upstream_http_adr_private_cache_seconds";

}
```

But this test **also fails**:

```
if ($upstream_http_adr_private_cache_seconds) {

    return 404;

}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Or is there another way to alter the `public` to `private` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives from `ngx_http_rewrite_module` are processed before evaluation of `$upstream_...` variables. You should't treat nginx config as programming language where your operations executed sequentaly as they appears in the source code. For example, there is no matter if you use `proxy_set_header` directive before the `proxy_pass` one or after it. Directives from `ngx_http_rewrite_module` is a special story, they are different from any other directives, you can read some details [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#internals).

For your case you can use `map` translation:

```
map $upstream_http_adr_private_cache_seconds $cache_control {
    ""       ""; # empty string if no custom header present
    default  "private, max-age=$upstream_http_adr_private_cache_seconds";
}
...
server {
    ...
    add_header Cache-Control $cache_control;
    ...
}
```

If the result of `$upstream_http_adr_private_cache_seconds` to `$cache_control` translation will be an empty string, nginx would not set Cache-Control (or any other HTTP header when an empty value passed as parameter value of add_header directive) at all.

**Update**

OP asked additional question:

> if a `Cache-Control: public` header already exists, then both headers remain (one `public`, one `private`), is there a way to remove the public one only if the custom header is found?

Here is the solution:

```
map $upstream_http_adr_private_cache_seconds $cache_control {
    ""       $upstream_http_cache_control; # use original upstream Cache-Control header if no custom header is given
    default  "private, max-age=$upstream_http_adr_private_cache_seconds";
}
...
server {
    ...
    proxy_hide_header Cache-Control; # clear Cache-Control header that came from upstream
    add_header Cache-Control $cache_control; # set Cache-Control header again
    ...
}
```

Comment: It works (thank you), but ... if a `Cache-Control: public` already exists, then both headers remain (one `public`, one `private`), is there a way to remove the public one only if the custom header is found ? I am lost at even trying to explain it. I did realize it doesn't work like programming but I am new to Nginx.

Comment: @adrianTNT Can you test an updated answer?

Comment: It seems to work perfectly now, I will do more tests. `proxy_clear_header` was unknown to my server, you meant `proxy_hide_header` right ? (I edited your answer) :)

Comment: It feels like we reinvented the wheel, should be common to want your own cache servers to cache your content but not the other external parties, isn't there some other way to allow the reverse proxy cache the content while maybe directly sending the final `private` directive from the origin server ?

Comment: [Here is](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/) detailed article about nginx caching, maybe `proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;` will do the trick. Can you test it?

Comment: I tested a bit, `proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;` made the cache server pass exact same origin headers to the final client, but it ignored the `Cache-Control` like `max-age=X` , so it didn't cache the page (ignored the header) Maybe I will experiment more, but for now I will use your solution.

Comment: From the article given above: The [`proxy_cache_valid`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_valid) directive enforces an expiration for the cached data and is required if ignoring `Cache-Control` headers. NGINX does not cache files that have no expiration.

Comment: yes, but `proxy_cache_valid` is a kind of fixed cache time; works for smaller, more static sites. Mine has many listings with different cache time.

Comment: Ivan, could you please have a look at a second question, I seen you are familiar with these settings, I am debugging for days: https://serverfault.com/questions/1003427/nginx-cache-same-url-first-returns-miss-to-all-chrome-curl-and-wget