# Is it safe to use proxy_ignore_headers Vary?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, cache, http-headers

I use a Nginx server that acts like a cache/reverse proxy for my Apache origin server.

I [was strugling to debug](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003427/nginx-cache-same-url-first-returns-miss-to-all-chrome-curl-and-wget) high rate of cache `MISS` when I found that it is because the response header `Vary: Accept-Encoding`, different www clients with different `Accept-Encoding` were not getting `HIT`, even thou same exact url was previously requested by another client.

This can be fixed by adding nginx config:

```
proxy_ignore_headers Vary;
```

After that, I get `HIT` cache replies.

**a)** Does this disable the different cached page variations **just** between my cache server and origin server ? (e.g it is safe to use)

**b)** Or does it cache one version (gzipped or not-gzipped file) for all final clients regardless of client's encoding/decoding capabilities ? I am thinking this could result in a non-gzip capable client receiving a gziped file ?

Even thou the cache is improved / fixed by the above directive, the final client still receives the `Vary: Accept-Encoding`, it can be hidden with `proxy_hide_header Vary`, but should I ?

Comment: Hi there ) I did some investigations, but can't continue them right now, in two days I have a deadline for my current project. Maybe you can do some additional testing?

Comment: Hi Ivan, I thought it was an easy yes/no thing, but you looked way more into it. I appreciate it. I have to keep current settings for a few days to see if my Google rankings recover, then I can do more testing about this, because I see it needs some more settings.

Answer (score 4):

I did some investigation on this subject. I think I found some valuable info on GitHub discussion in Yichun Zhang (author of OpenResty nginx fork) [reply](https://github.com/openresty/srcache-nginx-module/issues/11#issuecomment-60033833):

> I'd suggest the following options:
>
> 1. Cache both compressed and uncompressed responses, and add (a canonicalized) value of the Accept-Encoding to your cache key. So that clients which do not expect gzip'd responses result in a cache miss (and trigger caching the uncompressed version).
> 2. Cache compressed responses and use the standard ngx_gunzip module to uncompress the response body for those clients which do not accept gzip encoding:. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html But you need to be careful about nginx output filter order (between ngx_srcache's filter and ngx_gunzip's filter).
> 3. Only cache uncompressed content and rely on the ngx_gzip module to compress the data for those clients expecting gzip. Set proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ''; for example, if the proxy module is used as the content handler.

So, it looks like it isn't safe, and you should cache both (compressed and non-compressed) replies.

But what happens if you receive several requests with the following `Accept-Encoding` headers:

- `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
- `Accept-Encoding: gzip, br`
- `Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0.8, br;q=0.9`
- `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`

Does it mean that each of responses will be cached separately? I don't know yet, this needs more extensive testing that I already did. What I'm found so far:

- nginx does not respond to `Accept-Encoding: deflate` with deflated response (which is only a little different from gzipped one).
- nginx does not respect the weight qvalue part of header. It will respond with compressed response on request with `Accept-Encoding: identity;q=0.8, gzip;q=0.5` header. If you have a [`ngx_brotly`](https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli) module installed, nginx will always respond with brotly-compressed response if your `Accept-Encoding` request header contains a `br` compression method no matter what weights are specified for compression methods.

Yichun Zhang mentions about adding (a canonicalized) value of the Accept-Encoding to your cache key. This can be something like

```
map $http_accept_encoding $encoding_key {
    ~[\s:,]br(?:[\s,\;]|$)       2; # brotli
    ~[\s:,]gzip(?:[\s,\;]|$)     1; # gzip
    default                      0; # uncompressed
}
```

If you don't use `ngx_brotly` module, things can be simplified:

```
if ($http_accept_encoding ~ "[\s:,]gzip(?:[\s,;]|$)") {
    set $encoding_key 1;
}
```

After that adding `$encoding_key` variable to `proxy_cache_key` expression can do the trick, but as I already said, this needs more extensive testing.

Comment: The map regex is wrong, you need to escape semicolons, otherwise "nginx: [emerg] invalid number of the map parameters". I edited the regex and you reverted it.

Comment: @AlanDelval I was sure I tested that regex at the live server, and consider your corrections unnecessary, but it turns out that you were right. Either semicolon must be escaped of the full regex pattern should be single- or doublequoted. Sorry, reverted your corrections back.